# How To Read TXT File From A Server

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, xcode4

Here is the complete .m file :

```
#import "DevotionalView.h"

@implementation DevotionalView
@synthesize mytextview;
@synthesize mystring;



    - {void} awakeFromNib {
    NSURL *myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/text.txt"];
    NSString *mystring = [NSString stringWithContentOfURL:myurl];
    mytextview.text = mystring;
}


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
}
*/
```

@end

The errors are: '@end' is missing in implementation context  --where the @implementation DevotionalView is-- and at the {void} line it says Expected selector for objective-c method.

Thanks for taking the time to help!

The errors are: '@end' is missing in implementation context  --where the @implementation DevotionalView is-- and at the {void} line it says Expected selector for objective-c method.
Also, at the end of the file it say "expected method body"

Seems to work fine in the tutorial I followed, but it will not compile in XCode 4.3.

I'm using Storyboard-- will this change the part about NIB? I apologize for my lack of knowledge-- still getting used to this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What does "will not compile" mean? What specific error messages do you get? Please remember when posting here that we can't see your screen from here; we only have the information you provide us. Providing details makes it much easier for you to get a quick answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Sorry about that- I'll definitely be more descriptive from here on. Changed my original post to add more description- thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally worked around it-- from my searches it would appear that I had either messed up a delegate assignment or some such thing. So...(and you pros might groan at this) I opened up a new project (single view with a controller) and copied and pasted the controller, .h and .m files in, then used this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/test.txt"];
NSString *mystring = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myurl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding     error:&error]; 
newtext.text = mystring;
```

All is well!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have {}'s around the void in awakeFromNib they should be ()'s

Comment: Right you are! I changed them, but it only switched the error to "No know class method for selector 'stringwithcontentofurl'

Comment: stringWithContentsOfURL. You missed the s.

Comment: Haha! Right again: I was just editing it to put that I had googled it and found the 's' mistake. It does compile now, but 2 yellow warning signs, and it displays " return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));" in Thread1 main

Comment: I'd guess one of them is because stringWithContentsOfURL is deprecated. You can google for the replacement.  Don't know what the display stuff is from without more context.

Comment: Here is the main.m file that it highlights green `
`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}`
`  --the iphone simulator is only a black screen as well. Once again, thanks for taking the time to help me- would you happen to know of any tutorial that uses Xcode 4 and Storyboard that I should start from instead?

Comment: Deleted a comment as I realized I had tried to declare mystring twice, with one of them being flawed. Everything compiles, except still a black screen on the simulator and the green highlighted section mentioned above - with the Thread 1 : Signal Sigabrt error. Am I releasing something that's already being autoreleased?

Comment: Oh! And this: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<DevotionalView 0x7c9b610> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key storyboard.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e71022 0x2dcecd6 0x1e70ee1 0x1513022 0x1484f6b 0x1484edb 0xba3c88 0x149fd50 0xd8771a 0x1e72dea 0x1ddc7f1 0xd8626e 0xf8feef 0xf9003e 0xb64d7a 0xb64ff8 0xb6417f 0xb73183 0xb73c38 0xb67634 0x3162ef5 0x1e45195 0x1da9ff2 0x1da88da 0x1da7d84 0x1da7c9b 0xb63c65 0xb65626 0x249d 0x2405)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)